# Email Receiving Service - HTTP error response vs throw Exception

Tags: google-app-engine

If the processing of an email fails (eg. API timeout) should I return a 500 (404 ?) or throw an Exception.

Whilst it's undocumented I'm assuming that AppEngine with behave similarly to task queues and retry the http call to deliver the email. Is this a reasonable assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Since the mail system uses webhooks and interacts with App Engine at the HTTP level, your only option is to return an error status. If you throw an exception, your framework will convert this into a 500 response. That's a legitimate way to return a 500 - so how you do this is up to you.